# Modifying or sorting the WITH ROLLUP row

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to sort the oldest date if `WITH ROLLUP` is used?
Here's an example:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) as date, sum(qty) as qty FROM item group by id WITH ROLLUP
```

Would give me this:

```
+-----------------------+
| ID     | DAYS   | QTY |
+-----------------------+
| 1      | 437    | 17  |
| 2      | 38     | 33  |
| 3      | 14     | 49  |
| (null) | 14     | 99  |
+-----------------------+
```

But I am expecting:

```
+-----------------------+
| ID     | DAYS   | QTY |
+-----------------------+
| 1      | 437    | 17  |
| 2      | 38     | 33  |
| 3      | 14     | 49  |
| (null) | 437    | 99  |
+-----------------------+
```

I want the oldest date to display on that row. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the date in an aggregation function, then you can do what you want:

```
SELECT id, max(DATEDIFF(NOW(), date)) as date, sum(qty) as qty
FROM item
group by id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're a freaking genius! I should've thought of that! Thank you so much!